# Access value in subquery in view

Tags: sql, sqlite

As an example, I setup a simple SQLite schema like this:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (a TEXT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY(a, b));
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('x', 5);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('x', 10);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('x', 15);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('y', 5);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('y', 12);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('y', 16);
```

`b` represents a timestamp and `a` identifies an object. The real application contains more columns, of course.

I would like to create a view which contains a mapping of `(a, b)` to the next smaller value of `b` for which an entry exists in `foo`. It should look like this for the above example:

```
a  | b   | previous_b
---------------------
x  | 10  | 5
x  | 15  | 10
y  | 12  | 5
y  | 16  | 12
```

I tried to create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW prev
AS
    SELECT
        a,
        b AS current_b,
        (SELECT MAX(b) FROM foo WHERE b < current_b) AS previous_b
FROM foo;
```

However, it seems like I cannot access `current_b` in the subquery:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM prev;
Error: no such column: current_b
```

How can I solve this problem? If this is impossible, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aliases like that. Use

```
CREATE VIEW prev
AS
    SELECT
        f1.a,
        f1.b AS current_b,
        (SELECT MAX(f2.b) FROM foo f2 WHERE f2.b < f1.b) AS previous_b
    FROM foo as f1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had to add `AND f1.a = f2.a` and it worked! Will accept as soon as it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a correlated subquery.  So, you need table aliases and qualified column names:

```
CREATE VIEW prev AS
    SELECT f.a, f.b AS current_b,
          (SELECT MAX(f2.b) FROM foo f2 WHERE f2.a = b.a AND f2.b < f.b
          ) AS previous_b
    FROM foo f;
```

You should always use table aliases and qualified column names, especially if you are learning SQL.  Get the habits right when you are learning the language.

Comment: Thank you, it has been some time since I worked with SQL. I added `AND f1.a = f2.a` and it worked!